# Excel VBA Self-Destruct Switch

Tags: vba, excel

I have had my first "Client-took-my-work-and-then-ghosted-me-without-paying" experience. For the future, I want to put in a killswitch, disguised as a regular macro, which makes the whole thing unusable. That way, even if they hire someone to crack the password and remove my "Your trial has expired..." check, a normal-looking macro (Something like "Fix_Sheet_Formatting") would be easily overlooked and run, destroying everything and saving the changes.

However, that leaves the VBA... We're talking a full purge here, so everything must go. I'll figure out how to **do** all of this on my own, I just don't want to waste time pursuing something that isn't possible:

Can VBA code delete **itself** from a workbook **while running** or does it *have* to be deleted from a macro on another workbook? And would deleting the code cause the macro to stop running, or can I have it delete everything except a nasty MsgBox after everything is done?

Comment: [Maybe relevant](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/delete-module.htm)

Comment: Yes and no, you may try [writing the excel VBA itself](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) or with [this one](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Excel_VBproject_en.html), however, it's not hard to surpass it for some mid user, excel is not a reliable tool to keep copyrighted your job.

Comment: It looks like the hangup would be accessing the VBProject object. That would get caught by an antivirus and remove the module (And I don't want that because they'll need to use it to test it...or the killswitch will be removed).

Comment: Sorry, but IMO this is doomed. The only "safe" macro is a macro that isn't distributed. Look for a [good code obfuscation tool](http://www.crunchcode.de/en/index.html) instead, to make the VBA completely and utterly undecypherable (yet still functional); that way you can have a plain Boolean `IsDisabled` check that is outright impossible to tell from the rest of the code.

Comment: Hm - one way, although it'd be pretty slapdash, would be to somehow pull the VBEditor up, and use `SendKeys` to just "CTRL + A, DEL" everything.  I've accidentally put focus on the VBA Editor when using sendkeys, and it puts that info in there instead of my target document.  Also, I'm pretty sure VBA is not super secure, so if someone's clever enough, they'd be able to grab your code one way or another.  What about using an AddIn? (I know little about those, but maybe that's an option?)

Comment: Don't think this is a good idea, and the Self-Destruct Switch code can be manipulated without too much effort... unless you obfuscate your VBA code. If you are interested in VBA obfuscation, I'd recommend a tool call VBASH (www.ayedeal.com/vbash). It may help you protect your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll leave the comments to debating whether or not this is a good idea (IMHO it probably isn't).  As to the question itself, of course it's possible, and won't interrupt macro execution:

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim proj As Object
    Set proj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Dim comp As Object
    For Each comp In proj.VBComponents
        With comp.CodeModule
            .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            If comp.Name = "ThisWorkbook" Then
                .InsertLines 1, "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" & vbCrLf & _
                                vbTab & "MsgBox ""Where's my money, @#$%&!?""" & vbCrLf & _
                                "End Sub"
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Obfuscation is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: First time hearing about obfuscation. Much better solution.

Comment: @C-Love511 - On a more serious note (I just wanted to add that `MsgBox`), you might also take a look at running pre-assembled code.

Comment: @C-Love511 Note: without obfuscation, this code would destroy *the one copy of the macro-enabled workbook that's currently running*. If your user made copies, or even just backups of their network folders, they can always restore a backup and trick your code into believing that the trial is still in effect, until they figure out a way to crack the code and tweak it. Properly obfuscated, they can do that and crack open the code... only to find that there's nothing meaningful there to see, and that it's going to cost more to reverse-engineer *that* than to just pay you for your work.

Comment: Google search isn't bringing up anything meaningful for "pre-assembled VBA" or even "pre-assembled code". Is that another way of saying "Obfuscation" or was there a more specific resource you could point me to?

Comment: @C-Love511 - Sorry, gave you [the wrong search term](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=vb6+inline+assembly+language).

Comment: @C-Love511 Although this [site](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=A-new-method-for-disabling-the-Mouse-Scroll-Wheel-in-Access-forms) is for Access, the approach is entirely usable in any VBA host.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the info, too. While I'm learning about Obfuscation, I'm curious: how much would you charge a person *who knows nothing about computers* to hack a VBA password AND dig through a couple hundred lines of code to find any safety measures hidden inside, disguised as harmless functions in the code?

(The idea being that these seemingly normal-looking functions would destroy the way the code interacts with the sheets, requiring a new programmer to fix or recreate the sheets so they match up to the code.)

Comment: @C-Love511 - I'd just do it myself. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put a loop with due date as your payment data . Inside write code to get macro into infinity loop or to delete code.
If payment happens on time then just comment above piece of code or else just wait client come back to you on next day defined in loop.