# How to run macros only the first time the excel file opens

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some VBA code for my excel sheet. The thing is that I want it to run only once, i.e., when the user opens it for the first time.

if opened for second time or more, I want the excel to open normally without running that VBA code. How to do it using VBA or is there any excel feature?

Comment: Once per day or just once period? If it’s the latter why even make it a workbook open event?

Comment: Just once. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you just want to run this once it doesn’t really sound like a job for a workbook open event since the intent here is that it runs every time the book is open.... What does the code do exactly

Comment: Put it in `Workbook_Open`, then [delete the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129745/4088852).

Comment: The user downloads an excel sheet from a web application. After downloading, the data from one worksheet 1 is filtered and copied to a new created worksheet 2, and worksheet 1 is hidden. And after this, the user sees only WS2. So after this has happened, when the user opens the file next time he should be able to edit and save the WS2 file. Right now, the whole macro runs again and he cannot save any new data as the filtering process happens again.

Comment: So just store a flag somewhere and check for it when the workbook opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag in a cell in excel, when the excel opens each time, macros code checks if the value in that cell is "1". If is "1" then excel is opened for the first time, otherwise value of that cell is changed.

Following is the code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("your_wsname").Activate

'to check if it the file is being opened for the first time
If Cells(100, 100).Value = "1" Then
'value is blank if opening file for the first time
'if for first time then following happens
Else
    'call your methods here
    'set flag value 1 in one of the methods
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, give worksheet 2 a particular name and have the macro check for that name as its first task, if it finds it then end, if it does not find it then run the rest of the code...

Answer (score 0):

Store your code in an XLSM (as is necessary for there to be code in it).

- The user downloads that code from your website and opens it
- The `On_Open` fires

  - The code does whatever it currently does
  - The code then saves the file as an **XLSX** which will automatically delete all code since code cannot be stored in an XLSX format
- Wipes hands, job done.

Answer (score -2):

Below code will run once in a day, created another worksheet to record events like I did created a timeline in a worksheet called Event Recording and then let my macro check the value below that particular date if value is >0 then macro will not execute.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, i As Long, Cl As Long, Cntr As Long
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Event Recording")

    Cl = Sh.UsedRange.Cells.Find(What:=Date).Column
    Cntr = Sh.Cells(2, Cl)

    If Cntr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Hi"
    End If

    Sh.Cells(2, Cl) = Cntr + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Is "once per day" what the OP wants? I understood it was "one time only"...